# ngx-datatable sorting is not working correctly

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-datatables, ngx-datatable

Hi i'm facing a strange problem and i was wondering if you could provide any explanation that could help me.

In my datatable i'm displaying a string that can be either ["O titres"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGUaU.png) or ["100 %"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZNNI.png)
And if i click on the column to sort it actually does something but its not sorting properly and i have no idea why [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVjrJ.png)

Do you know why am i facing this problem ? Do you know what the sorting is based on for the ngx datatable ? 
Thank you

Comment: Without code example, we cannot tell what you're doing wrong

Comment: @marcant0 there's no code to show i'm using the basic sort function given by angular for ngx datatable

Comment: Look like the data is not sorted. Please create [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) by providing minimal code. attempt with sample data in the question or [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com). Else it is hard for Stack Overflow-er to reproduce and debug your error. Thanks.